# Problem with finding printer status using WMI in .NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, wmi

I am working on a project in `.NET Core` and need to get printer status information on my client. I am using `WMI` (Windows Management Instrumentation) for this task. My code looks like this:

```
public async Task<Response> PrinterStateByName(string sessionId, string printerName)
    {
        string query = string.Format($"SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE NAME = '{printerName}' ");
        

        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

            if (searcher is not null)
            {
                _logger.LogError("není null");
            }

            foreach (ManagementObject printer in searcher.Get())
            {
                string name = printer["Name"] as string;
                string status = printer["Status"] as string;
                bool isDefault = (bool)printer["Default"];
                bool isOnline = (bool)printer["WorkOffline"];
                bool isOutOfPaper = (bool)printer["OutOfPaper"];

                _logger.LogInformation($"Printer Name: {name}");
                _logger.LogInformation($"Printer State: {status}");
                _logger.LogInformation($"Is Printer Default: {isDefault}");
                _logger.LogInformation($"Online state: {!isOnline}");
                _logger.LogInformation($"Out of the Paper: {isOutOfPaper}");


            }

        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error during getting informations about: {e.Message}");
        }

       
        var result = _mediator.Send(new SendPrinterStateByName_Command(printerName));
        return new Response(false, result, null, sessionId);
    }`
```

The problem I'm having is that the code always throws a `Not Found` error, even if I use the correct printer name (obtained from `Name` or `DeviceID`). I have made sure that the name is exactly the same as the printer on my device.

Would anyone have a guess as to what might be causing this error? Could it be permissions issues or some other configuration that I have overlooked?

Comment: You can try utilizing LIKE in your query, since there might be spaces. The WMI uses the drivers, and the name might be different or have extra spaces somewhere in it

Comment: I have found out that the `Exception` throws there `isOutOfPaper`

Comment: @Demon How to get state `isOutOfPaper`?

Comment: According to the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printer there is no field called "OutOfPaper" at all